# md-sidenav-container in angular2 material does not show content

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use the below an the side nav does not show.  If I add content the sidebar shows.  Wow..

```
<md-sidenav-container mode="side" >
  <md-sidenav #sidenav  opened="true" style="background-color: green">
        Dude!!!!!!
  </md-sidenav>

  <div class="my-content" style="background-color: blue">
    <router-outlet name="servicelistright"></router-outlet>
  </div>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

e.g. I add content then works. How so I resolve this silly issue?

```
   <div class="my-content" style="background-color: blue">
    Whats the deleio?
    <router-outlet name="servicelistright"></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could it be that the width of your page is too small when you don't have any content? So the sidemenu doesn't have any place to display itself in?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't see your sidenav unless you fill your `<md-sidenav-container>` with content is the `<md-sidenav>` overlap (in case of `over` mode, or just push in `side` mode) your `<md-sidenav-container>`.

Therefore as long as your container does not contain anything, it's empty and an empty div doesn't have any height, so does your related sidenav.

Answer (score 0):

```
<md-sidenav-container class="container-fluid">
  <!-- separating content between each other -->   
  <div class="col-md-1">
      <button md-button (click)="sidenav.open()">
           <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-11">
    Main content goes here
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>

  <!-- below contains elements for menu strip -->
  <md-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav">
   Menu bar
  </md-sidenav>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

Note: `<br>` is added to create a height.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/UUFltEZ0VowRsMpDuDvN?p=preview)**